# How to get latest date key-value pair from json array including parent keys

Tags: json, jq

1) I am trying to generate a CSV file using jq from a json.
2) I need parent keys along with one key-value pair from the child array
3) Which ever value has latest date in it , will be the resulting key-value pair
4) Need to generate a csv out of that result

This is my json

```
{
    "students": [
        {
            "name": "Name1",
            "class": "parentClass1",
            "teacher": "teacher1",
            "attendance": [
                {
                    "key": "class1",
                    "value": "01-DEC-2018"
                },
                {
                    "key": "class1",
                    "value": "28-Nov-2018"
                },
                {
                    "key": "class1",
                    "value": "26-Oct-2018"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Name2",
            "class": "parentClass2",
            "teacher": "teacher2",
            "attendance": [
                {
                    "key": "class2",
                    "value": "05-DEC-2018"
                },
                {
                    "key": "class2",
                    "value": "25-Nov-2018"
                },
                {
                    "key": "class2",
                    "value": "20-Oct-2018"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I did not made much progress I am trying to create csv like this

```
jq  '.students[] | [.name, .class, attendance[].key,.properties[].value] | @csv ' main.json
```

Below is expected CSV from that json

```
Name         ParentClass        key         dateValue                                                                           Summary
Name1        parentClass1      class1       150 days ago(difference with today date with latest date i.e 01-DEC-2018 )         Teacher1.parentClass1
Name2        parentClass2      class2       150 days ago(difference with today date with latest date i.e 05-DEC-2018 )         Teacher2.parentClass2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parse dates using `strptime` and assign the result to *value*s, thus you can get the latest *attendance* using `max_by`. Convert the *value* to seconds since Epoch using `mktime`, substract it from *now*, divide by 24 * 60 * 60 to get number of days since.

```
$ jq -r '
def days_since:
  (now - .) / 86400 | floor;
.students[]
| [ .name, .class ] +
  ( .attendance
    | map(.value |= strptime("%d-%b-%Y"))
    | max_by(.value)
    | [ .key, "\(.value | mktime | days_since) days ago" ]
  ) +
  [ .teacher + "." + .class ]
| @tsv' file
Name1   parentClass1    class1  148 days ago    teacher1.parentClass1
Name2   parentClass2    class2  144 days ago    teacher2.parentClass2
```

Note that this solution doesn't deal with daylight saving time changes.

Comment: What about daylight saving time changes?

Comment: @hek2mgl this solution doesn't adress them. do you have any advice?

Comment: For a production solution, `jq` simply can't being used here. I would use `Python`

Comment: @hek2mgl Oh, then I should add a note about it. Thanks for warning

Answer (score 1):

For production purposes `jq` can't be used here because it doesn't allow to perform daylight saving time safe date calculations.

I would use Python because it allows to perform daylight saving time safe date calculations, comes with json support by default and is installed on most to all UNIX derivates.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
from datetime import datetime
import json


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('filename')
    return parser.parse_args()


def main():
    args = parse_args()
    with open(args.filename) as file_desc:
        data = json.load(file_desc)

    print('Name\tParentClass\tkey\tdateValue')

    today = datetime.today()
    for record in data['students']:
        for a in record['attendance']:
            date = datetime.strptime(a['value'], '%d-%b-%Y')
            a['since'] = (today - date).days
        last = sorted(record['attendance'], key=lambda x: x['since'])[0]
        print('\t'.join([
            record['name'],
            record['class'],
            last['key'],
            '{} days ago'.format(last['since']),
            '{}.{}'.format(record['teacher'], record['class']),
        ]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output (on the day when this answer was written):

```
Name    ParentClass Key DateValue   Summary
Name1   parentClass1    class1  148 days ago    teacher1.parentClass1
Name2   parentClass2    class2  144 days ago    teacher2.parentClass2
```